# how to expand TextField to full width in the grid container?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

The `TextField` component is not drawn to full width while
the `Paper` component is drawn to full width.
Does somebody have any idea?

```js
<Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.grid}>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>

  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>2</Paper>
  </Grid>

  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>6</Paper>
  </Grid>

  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>7</Paper>
  </Grid>

  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>8</Paper>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `fullWidth` to `true` in your `TextField`. You can see all `Input` props [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#main-content) for more reference.

```js
<Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
  <TextField
    fullWidth
    id="outlined-basic"
    label="Outlined"
    variant="outlined"
  />
</Grid>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64215994/how-to-fit-text-field-elements-into-the-grid-container-using-material-ui]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.